# Cannot convert model into list<model>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to convert model into list after doing assingments

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string roleId)
        {
            var model = new PermissionViewModel();
            var allPermissions = new List<RoleClaimsViewModel>();
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Products), roleId);
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Services), roleId);
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Projects), roleId);
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Blogs), roleId);
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
            model.RoleId = roleId;
            model.RoleName = role.Name;
            
            var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            var allClaimValues = allPermissions.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var roleClaimValues = claims.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var authorizedClaims = allClaimValues.Intersect(roleClaimValues).ToList();
            foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
            {
                if (authorizedClaims.Any(a => a == permission.Value))
                {
                    permission.Selected = true;
                }
            }

            model.ToList();

            return View("/Views/Backend/Usermanagment/Permission/Index1.cshtml", model);
        }
```

I cannot make model.Tolist(); to work,
any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var listModel = new List<PermissionViewModel>{ model };
```

if your view model is `List<PermissionViewModel>`

Update:

if i understand the issue right, your codes must be something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string roleId)
    {
        var model = new PermissionViewModel();
        var allPermissions = new List<RoleClaimsViewModel>();
        allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Products), roleId);
        allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Services), roleId);
        allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Projects), roleId);
        allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Constants.Permissions.Blogs), roleId);
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
        model.RoleId = roleId;
        model.RoleName = role.Name;
        
        var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
        var allClaimValues = allPermissions.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
        var roleClaimValues = claims.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
        var authorizedClaims = allClaimValues.Intersect(roleClaimValues).ToList();
        foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
        {
            if (authorizedClaims.Any(a => a == permission.Value))
            {
                permission.Selected = true;
            }
        }

        model.RoleClaims = allPermissions;

        return View("/Views/Backend/Usermanagment/Permission/Index1.cshtml", model);
    }
```

in view use this loop:

```
@model ClaimTreeView.Models.PermissionViewModel 

@* some codes *@

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RoleClaims.Count(); i++) {}
```

Comment: The thing is that my view model is PermissionViewModel not List<PermissionViewModel> and if I make it List<permissionViewModel> I cannot do assignment like:          
            model.RoleId = roleId;
            model.RoleName = role.Name;                                                                                            so I want to make assignment to the model and convert to List or the other way around

Comment: you must use my codes after assignment. I am changing your model to list after creating model. Can you share view codes as well so we can help you better?

Comment: sorry, i mean the cshtml code for this path "/Views/Backend/Usermanagment/Permission/Index1.cshtml" to see how you will use your model in your view. but thanks it helps also

Comment: In View I want to make TreeView but notice that the view is still not fully completed yet;               here it is                                                                                                                                          ``` 
@model List<ClaimTreeView.Models.PermissionViewModel>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/tree.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="panel panel-primary">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="tree">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {}   See the first line in code

Comment: i edited my answer, if i understand you right you dont need list model you need to loop through property of model which is list.